# joomla 1.5.6 menu doesn't appear after php update

Tags: php, joomla, joomla1.5

after updating my server php tp 5.3.3 the menu on joomla 1.5.6 doesn't work any more,
when I turned on the debug mode the below message appears

```
Profile Information
Application afterLoad: 0.005 seconds, 0.52 MB
Application afterInitialise: 0.877 seconds, 4.12 MB
Application afterRoute: 0.881 seconds, 4.45 MB
Application afterDispatch: 0.930 seconds, 6.21 MB
Application afterRender: 0.956 seconds, 6.64 MB
Memory Usage
7002564
10 queries logged
1.  DELETE 
  FROM jos_session 
  WHERE ( time < '1329434797' )
2.  SELECT * 
  FROM jos_session 
  WHERE session_id = 'vrklkcuiohl12g3la0lm4gp5v3'
3.  UPDATE `jos_session` 
  SET `time`='1329435697',`userid`='0',`usertype`='',`username`='',`gid`='0',`guest`='1',`client_id`='0',`data`='__default|a:7:{s:15:\"session.counter\";i:3;s:19:\"session.timer.start\";i:1329434953;s:18:\"session.timer.last\";i:1329435238;s:17:\"session.timer.now\";i:1329435250;s:22:\"session.client.browser\";s:69:\"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:10.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0.1\";s:8:\"registry\";O:9:\"JRegistry\":3:{s:17:\"_defaultNameSpace\";s:7:\"session\";s:9:\"_registry\";a:1:{s:7:\"session\";a:1:{s:4:\"data\";O:8:\"stdClass\":0:{}}}s:7:\"_errors\";a:0:{}}s:4:\"user\";O:5:\"JUser\":19:{s:2:\"id\";i:0;s:4:\"name\";N;s:8:\"username\";N;s:5:\"email\";N;s:8:\"password\";N;s:14:\"password_clear\";s:0:\"\";s:8:\"usertype\";N;s:5:\"block\";N;s:9:\"sendEmail\";i:0;s:3:\"gid\";i:0;s:12:\"registerDate\";N;s:13:\"lastvisitDate\";N;s:10:\"activation\";N;s:6:\"params\";N;s:3:\"aid\";i:0;s:5:\"guest\";i:1;s:7:\"_params\";O:10:\"JParameter\":7:{s:4:\"_raw\";s:0:\"\";s:4:\"_xml\";N;s:9:\"_elements\";a:0:{}s:12:\"_elementPath\";a:1:{i:0;s:63:\"/usr/www/users/mysite/libraries/joomla/html/parameter/element\";}s:17:\"_defaultNameSpace\";s:8:\"_default\";s:9:\"_registry\";a:1:{s:8:\"_default\";a:1:{s:4:\"data\";O:8:\"stdClass\":0:{}}}s:7:\"_errors\";a:0:{}}s:9:\"_errorMsg\";N;s:7:\"_errors\";a:0:{}}}' 
  WHERE session_id='vrklkcuiohl12g3la0lm4gp5v3'
4.  SELECT * 
  FROM jos_components 
  WHERE parent = 0
5.  SELECT folder AS type, element AS name, params 
  FROM jos_plugins 
  WHERE published >= 1 
  AND access <= 0 
  ORDER BY ordering
6.  SELECT m.*, c.`option` AS component 
  FROM jos_menu AS m 
  LEFT JOIN jos_components AS c 
  ON m.componentid = c.id 
  WHERE m.published = 1 
  ORDER BY m.sublevel, m.parent, m.ordering
7.  SELECT template 
  FROM jos_templates_menu 
  WHERE client_id = 0 
  AND (menuid = 0 OR menuid = 1) 
  ORDER BY menuid DESC 
  LIMIT 0, 1
8.  SELECT a.id, a.title, a.title_alias, a.introtext, a.fulltext, a.sectionid, a.state, a.catid, a.created, a.created_by, a.created_by_alias, a.modified, a.modified_by, a.checked_out, a.checked_out_time, a.publish_up, a.publish_down, a.images, a.attribs, a.urls, a.metakey, a.metadesc, a.access, CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(a.alias) THEN CONCAT_WS(':', a.id, a.alias) ELSE a.id END AS slug, CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(cc.alias) THEN CONCAT_WS(":", cc.id, cc.alias) ELSE cc.id END AS catslug, CHAR_LENGTH( a.`fulltext` ) AS readmore, u.name AS author, u.usertype, g.name AS groups, cc.title AS category, s.title AS section, s.ordering AS s_ordering, cc.ordering AS cc_ordering, a.ordering AS a_ordering, f.ordering AS f_ordering 
  FROM jos_content AS a 
  INNER JOIN jos_content_frontpage AS f 
  ON f.content_id = a.id 
  LEFT JOIN jos_categories AS cc 
  ON cc.id = a.catid 
  LEFT JOIN jos_sections AS s 
  ON s.id = a.sectionid 
  LEFT JOIN jos_users AS u 
  ON u.id = a.created_by 
  LEFT JOIN jos_groups AS g 
  ON a.access = g.id 
  WHERE 1 
  AND a.access <= 0 
  AND a.state = 1 
  AND (( cc.published = 1 
  AND s.published = 1 ) OR ( a.catid = 0 
  AND a.sectionid = 0 ) ) 
  AND ( a.publish_up = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR a.publish_up <= '2012-02-16 23:41:37' ) 
  AND ( a.publish_down = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR a.publish_down >= '2012-02-16 23:41:37' ) 
  ORDER BY  f.ordering 
  LIMIT 0, 9
9.  SELECT a.id, a.title, a.title_alias, a.introtext, a.fulltext, a.sectionid, a.state, a.catid, a.created, a.created_by, a.created_by_alias, a.modified, a.modified_by, a.checked_out, a.checked_out_time, a.publish_up, a.publish_down, a.images, a.attribs, a.urls, a.metakey, a.metadesc, a.access, CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(a.alias) THEN CONCAT_WS(':', a.id, a.alias) ELSE a.id END AS slug, CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(cc.alias) THEN CONCAT_WS(":", cc.id, cc.alias) ELSE cc.id END AS catslug, CHAR_LENGTH( a.`fulltext` ) AS readmore, u.name AS author, u.usertype, g.name AS groups, cc.title AS category, s.title AS section, s.ordering AS s_ordering, cc.ordering AS cc_ordering, a.ordering AS a_ordering, f.ordering AS f_ordering 
  FROM jos_content AS a 
  INNER JOIN jos_content_frontpage AS f 
  ON f.content_id = a.id 
  LEFT JOIN jos_categories AS cc 
  ON cc.id = a.catid 
  LEFT JOIN jos_sections AS s 
  ON s.id = a.sectionid 
  LEFT JOIN jos_users AS u 
  ON u.id = a.created_by 
  LEFT JOIN jos_groups AS g 
  ON a.access = g.id 
  WHERE 1 
  AND a.access <= 0 
  AND a.state = 1 
  AND (( cc.published = 1 
  AND s.published = 1 ) OR ( a.catid = 0 
  AND a.sectionid = 0 ) ) 
  AND ( a.publish_up = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR a.publish_up <= '2012-02-16 23:41:37' ) 
  AND ( a.publish_down = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR a.publish_down >= '2012-02-16 23:41:37' ) 
  ORDER BY  f.ordering
10. SELECT id, title, module, position, content, showtitle, control, params 
  FROM jos_modules AS m 
  LEFT JOIN jos_modules_menu AS mm 
  ON mm.moduleid = m.id 
  WHERE m.published = 1 
  AND m.access <= 0 
  AND m.client_id = 0 
  AND ( mm.menuid = 1 OR mm.menuid = 0 ) 
  ORDER BY position, ordering
0 legacy queries logged
Language Files Loaded
•   /usr/www/users/mysite/language/en-GB/en-GB.ini 1
•   /usr/www/users/mysite/language/en-GB/en-GB.plg_system_debug.ini 1
•   /usr/www/users/mysite/language/en-GB/en-GB.com_content.ini 1
•   /usr/www/users/mysite/language/en-GB/en-GB.tpl_js_weblogic_brown.ini 
•   /usr/www/users/mysite/language/en-GB/en-GB.mod_breadcrumbs.ini 1
•   /usr/www/users/mysite/language/en-GB/en-GB.mod_search.ini 1
•   /usr/www/users/mysite/language/en-GB/en-GB.mod_mainmenu.ini 1
Untranslated Strings Diagnostic
None
Untranslated Strings Designer
None
```

PHP error as below

```
"17 Feb 2012 12:50:36","/usr/www/users/mysite/libraries/joomla/language/language.php: 336","(Warning) file_get_contents(/usr/www/users/mysite/language/en-GB/en-GB.tpl_js_weblogic_brown.ini): failed to open stream: No such file or directory"
"17 Feb 2012 12:50:36","/usr/www/users/mysite/libraries/joomla/language/language.php: 336","(Warning) file_get_contents(/usr/www/users/mysite/language/en-GB/en-GB.tpl_js_weblogic_brown.ini): failed to open stream: No such file or directory"
"17 Feb 2012 12:50:49","/usr/www/users/mysite/libraries/joomla/language/language.php: 336","(Warning) file_get_contents(/usr/www/users/mysite/language/en-GB/en-GB.tpl_js_weblogic_brown.ini): failed to open stream: No such file or directory"
"17 Feb 2012 12:50:49","/usr/www/users/mysite/libraries/joomla/language/language.php: 336","(Warning) file_get_contents(/usr/www/users/mysite/language/en-GB/en-GB.tpl_js_weblogic_brown.ini): failed to open stream: No such file or directory"
"17 Feb 2012 13:19:34","/usr/www/users/mysite/plugins/content/plugin_googlemap2.php: 432","(Deprecated) Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated"
"17 Feb 2012 13:30:52","/usr/www/users/mysite/plugins/content/plugin_googlemap2.php: 432","(Deprecated) Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated"
"17 Feb 2012 13:31:00","/usr/www/users/mysite/plugins/content/plugin_googlemap2.php: 432","(Deprecated) Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated"
```

Any body can help to solve this and make my menu work again?

Comment: you have mentioned server side logs. Please mention the php errors. So it will be easy to identify the issues.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall the template and the menu shall appear again.

Comment: The topmenu items doesn't appear on joomla admin panel too, it's not belong to the template

Answer (score 0):

And what about upgrading your Joomla to the latest version?

Answer (score 0):

What are the menus which are not appearing?
front-end menus or back-end menus?

Also, have you tried to reinstall the admin menu too?
This problem is common when updating Joomla, and usually because the template menus are hardcoded.

-- Edit
Just noticed the error messages you posted below.

```
"17 Feb 2012 12:50:36","/usr/www/users/mysite/libraries/joomla/language/language.php: 336","(Warning) file_get_contents(/usr/www/users/mysite/language/en-GB/en-GB.tpl_js_weblogic_brown.ini): failed to open stream: No such file or directory"
```

This one indicates you have a missing language file (file name: en-GB.tpl_js_weblogic_brown.ini), related to the template (weblogic brown style). maybe this is the reason for disappeared menu.